# VS Code recognizes custom.d.ts only when it's open

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have some custom Typescript declarations in a `custom.d.ts` file, and VS code will read my TS correctly when that file is open, however if the file is closed, VSCode does not "know" about those TS definitions, and I get red underlines all over my code.

One catch is that my `tsconfig.json` file is NOT in the root directory, and neither is my `custom.d.ts` file. Why? Because config files in a root directory is so stupid, and I hate it. Why can't config files like that go in a config directory???

Anyway, how can I instruct VSCode to KNOW about my `custom.d.ts` file? Again, if the file is open, VSCode knows about those definitions, but when I close the file, VSCode forgets about those definitions and the rest of typescript gets red error underlines...

Directory Structure:

```
/
| - package.json
| - .gitignore
| - client/
    | - client source code.... 
| - server/
    | - @types/
        | - custom.d.ts 
    | - configs/ 
        | - tsconfig.json
        | - .develop.env
```

Comment: This is probably a TSC configuration issue more so than a VS Code issue. Is there anyway I could get you to post your `tsconfig.json` & `package.json` files?

Comment: Is this on your local machine and are you using a container? If its not on your local machine, then can you mention again whether or not your using a container, or if your deploying strait from a VM instance (i.e. like straight from a Linux directory running on an amazon ec2 instance, or an Azure/Google equivalent)?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the client is importing stuff from /server, and that server has its own package.json file, you probably want to add `{ "types": "./@types/custom.d.ts" }` to the /server dist's package.json

Answer (score 0):

I have badly opened VS Code workspace, from folder that do not contain tsconfig.json file ‍♂️